# How many controllers to make in a framework generally?

Tags: zend-framework, model-view-controller, frameworks, controller

I was wondering if there are any guidelines for the number of controllers to make in any web based frameworks. I know it depends on the requirement. But still if you would consider a basic application containing signup, login, user authentication, Sending emails, User Profile Edit etc..how do you decide about the controllers?

And if there are many common functions would you make a different controllers to hold them all? Some frameworks like Zend recommend to create helper files for that! Do you create category of helper files for different functions?

Comment: Do you mean bootstrap files that are named in the URL, such as "myapp.php" (or via htaccess, if you're doing routing) or actual business logic implementations? For the former, you can get away with one (or one per environment, as per symfony) but for the latter, it's as many as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at routing we have some sort of a guideline as to how many controllers and even actions we will have in Zend Framework. Although we have to keep in mind that we can do quite a few things to change this in one way (getting less) or another (have even more).

The basic and general rule in ZF for routing is to have a link path matching up with controllers and actions.

```
www.yourdomain.com/controller/action
```

Routing will dispatch to the corresponding controller and with it to the named action. When we follow this basic rule we will end up with a number of controllers that matches our number of paths we like to see.

You can basically create a root path for every piece of functionality for you website and end up with as many controller (with one action) or even combine everything within one path and hence one controller but as many actions.

Ultimately you will and should combine common features of your website into one path and controller, e.g. combine everything related to user management (signup, profile edit) into a `/user` path and UserController.

As for your examples I think User authentication is something that will not have its own controller but happen inside the Login controller or models used by that controller.

**UPDATE**

Controllers and their actions interpret requests and should only delegate to other methods. It may be beneficial to keep these methods in their own classes. How you structure this methods and classes is up to you. The Zend way is to keep them in your own application library, e.g. sending emails should be held and performed by a separate class in your own application library (next to and maybe extending Zend classes).

If you have a contact page you could have a `/contact` link with a ContactController. The indexAction will delegate everything to present the form page. The form could have a `/contact/submit` link for the submit button and a corresponding submitAction will hook up your email library class and send out the email. The submitAction finally may call something like `_redirect('/submit/thankyou')` or even `/submit/error`. As you may guess by now there will be a thankyouAction responsible for presenting a Thank you page or a errorAction to let the user know there was an error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What about the email functionality? If i have lots of emails to send to user - like welcome emails, email verification mails, emails related to application , etc and how do you stick to OOP for the controllers. Most time I end up writing many lines of code in a single action.